# What is the path of the `top` program?

Tags: linux

Where is the `top` program? What is the file path to the program that I usually just call with a `top` statement in bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out by running

```
type top
```

It's usually `/usr/bin/top`, but it depends on the distribution. It can also be aliased to `htop` etc.

Comment: That works locally, but what if I'm on a VM (EC2) and I get 
"bash: type: top: not found"
do I need to install it?

Comment: figured it out had to update sources.list & install htop on debian